# calendric calculations in iOS broken before 1577... (julian -> gregorian)

Tags: iphone, ios, nscalendar

The same code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy GG"];
//13th of December 1577
NSDate * aDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:-12371067248]; 

NSString * formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:aDate];
```

Mac OS X target shows formattedDate correctly

> 13th of December 1577

iOS 5.0 target shows

> 23rd of December 1577

as if the Julian -> Gregorian transition was bugged

Any ideas how to overcome that?

Comment: Special-case it, I suppose.  Keep in mind that the transition date is purely arbitrary, and Gregorian wasn't fully adopted until about 300 years later.

Comment: Well, it does show that the implementations are different and one is clearly broken. In my case I stumbled upon it while serializing the dates to SQLite... Being aware of conversion issues, I thought I'd be safer keeping an interval..

Comment: Please file a bug report at http://radar.apple.com

Comment: Not necessarily broken, just different.

Comment: No, it really is broken. Different would be if I could configure it either way...

Comment: Anyway, doing something else to achieve the same result, and filed a Radar

Comment: I find the Mac behavior "broken", since it doesn't provide a consistent interface where you can control the (arbitrary and inconsistent) decision of when to switch to Julian.

Comment: Pick a date when the transition should occur: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Timeline

Comment: I call it broken because behavior is inconsistent between two sister platforms. Whether it should be configurable etc. is an entirely different story...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running this code on both Mac and iOS

```
NSDateFormatter *localFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
localFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
localFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"g"];  // g = julian day number
NSDate *d2299159 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2299159"];
NSDate *d2299160 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2299160"];
NSDate *d2299161 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2299161"];
NSDate *d2299162 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2299162"];


NSLog(@"Julian Day Number 2299159 = %@", [localFormatter stringFromDate:d2299159]);
NSLog(@"Julian Day Number 2299160 = %@", [localFormatter stringFromDate:d2299160]);
NSLog(@"Julian Day Number 2299161 = %@", [localFormatter stringFromDate:d2299161]);
NSLog(@"Julian Day Number 2299162 = %@", [localFormatter stringFromDate:d2299162]);
```

and you wil get these outputs (except the <-- notes):

**Mac**

```
Julian Day Number 2299159 = 1582-10-03   <-- Julian calendar
Julian Day Number 2299160 = 1582-10-04   <-- Julian calendar
Julian Day Number 2299161 = 1582-10-15   <-- Gregorian calendar
Julian Day Number 2299162 = 1582-10-16   <-- Gregorian calendar
```

**iOS**

```
Julian Day Number 2299159 = 1582-10-13   <-- Proleptic Gregorian calendar
Julian Day Number 2299160 = 1582-10-14   <-- Proleptic Gregorian calendar
Julian Day Number 2299161 = 1582-10-15   <-- Gregorian calendar
Julian Day Number 2299162 = 1582-10-16   <-- Gregorian calendar
```

On the Mac NSDateFormatter switches to the Julian calendar (also called old style dates) for dates preceding Oct 15, 1582 which is the first day in the Gregorian calendar (that Apple works with. Some countries adopted on different dates).
If you refer to Gregorian dates before this date, these dates are in the proleptic Gregorian calendar, meaning, dates before the Gregorian existed. And, as you can see from the second output NSDateFormatter on the iOS platform doesn't switch to the Julian calendar but stays in the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
The difference in your output is exactly those 10 skipped days that were skipped in the transition from the Julian to the Gregorian.

I can highly recommend this applet if you want to play around with different calendars to learn more about this stuff: 
http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachum/calendar-book/Calendrica.html
These guys also wrote a brilliant book on the subject.

Also, Apple has a little section on Historical Dates in their documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtHist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010240-SW1
However, they do not mention NSDateFormatter implementation differences on different platforms!

Working with calendars is from hell - good luck :-)

Comment: That is one great answer. Thanks a lot. I finally managed to solve this particular problem in a slightly different way, but this post will help someone else who'll undoubtedly run into it. I eventually managed to ship my app (shameless plug [historysurferapp.com](http://www.historysurferapp.com)) without relying on the iOS implementation of NSDateFormatter

Comment: Ah, maybe to add to that - when I was researching that particular problem I was initially dead certain that I did something horribly wrong, read everything I could find about Julian -> Gregorian transition. I ended up filing a RADAR claiming that there was a bug on iOS - I basically assumed the Mac implementation to be the right one, since it follows the "adoption" (it was really a gradual process, here in the sense of backward chronology) to Gregorian of most mainland European countries - at least if I am to believe wikipedia.

Comment: Glad you managed to solve your problem. I only discovered this because I ran some unit tests on the Mac and then moved them to iOS and suddenly some tests failed. Apple could/should be a little more informative about this stuff IMHO.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. I watched the calendric calculations session from WWDC twice hoping it would give me some clues. I figured it was the transition, but they talked about it as if iOS and OS X implementations were identical.

Comment: And honestly I have still to run tests to see whether it is NSCalendar, NSDate or NSDateFormatter that is the culprit, but knowing what I told in my answer above works for now. However, I suspect that it is NSCalendar.

Comment: I note that in Swift, which uses `Calendar` rather than `NSCalendar`, they seem to also use the proleptic rather than the Julian on *both* iOS & MacOS - but this isn't documented as far as I can see...